# Absolute angle or position measurement for slow movements

Tags: sensor, accelerometer, magnetometer, position-sensor

I would like to monitor the movement of an extremely slow object. The x,y,z-position is not really relevant to me, I am more interested in the angle.
I have come across the MPU6050 that is explained here:
https://howtomechatronics.com/tutorials/arduino/arduino-and-mpu6050-accelerometer-and-gyroscope-tutorial/

but even though it has a motion processor that corrects drift I think this is not going to work as my object cannot move for several hours up to 1-2 days.

Thus, I was thinking about a magnetometer as this one: QMC5883L-TR as a suitable IC.

I think it is not recommended to ask for specific products on stackexchange so please let me rephrase my question: what measurement technique do you think is suitable for me? I can find the appropriate modules then.

Edit to clarify my contraints:
@Kartman it is fine for me to use an absolute angle sensor. In  the installation, I am already using a  small neodymium magnet (8mm diameter, 4mm thickness) that is placed around 10cm away from the point where I need to install the angle sensor. The used sensor should not interfere with that magnet field. Can you please recommend absolute angle sensors?

@jonk accuracy of +-2-5° is ok (drift is very bad), 1measurement each 1min is fine, the only difficulty I see is the very slow movement and eventually the interference with a neodymium magnet that I am already using in the setup for a hall effect sensor.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use an absolute angle sensor? Eg encoder?

Comment: This is both a sensor question as well as a processing question. I don't think much can be said that's truly useful without significant details about the object, how an angle is to be measured, the required accuracy, precision, and repeatability. Probably still more than that. Can you say anything more, at all?

Comment: @Kartman thank you, I have updated my question accordingly. Using an absolute sensor would be fine. Can you recommend sth. there?

Comment: @jonk I have updated my main question accordingly, thank you! Sensor does not need to be accurate or fast but should not show any drift over time or interfere heavily with a neodymium magnet that I am already using in the setup.

Comment: There are absolute angle hall effect encoders that could use that magnet. These are used in automotive applications for throttle position and throttle pedal sensing. Or something like an optical absolute encoder.

Comment: The QMC5883 would be driven crazy by your magnet!

Comment: @Kartman the neodymium magnet would be placed 10cm away from the QMC5883 + I would be fine if the magnet adds a lot of 'offset' to the measurement as long as I can still resolve changes in the QMC5883 outputs without a drift. I guess for the couple of EUROs for the breakout board, I will just test the QMC5883 but I'm worried that is is not leading anywhere.

Comment: Companies like AMS have specific sensors for measuring the angle of a magnet. A magnetometer is used for measuring angle in relation to the earth’s magnetic field.

Comment: @MarcoBobinger Drift over time is a difficult problem -- especially when talking over the web like this. That's exactly the kind of thing for which a great deal of information is required. Also, 10 cm is a ***long*** distance for any magnetic field to reach. These two details you've exposed make me unwilling to spend any additional time without lots more details from you. Daily and annual temperature variations, or at least the exact period over which drift isn't permitted (and the degree of drift allowed within that period) just to name one such thing. Rffort just isn't worth it otherwise.